# VisualStudio breakpoint is triggered without the actual line being executed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I have a project in Unreal Engine 4 and I am debugging the game code in Visual Studio 2019. There are some cases when a breakpoint is hit but I believe the code is not really executed. Can you please tell me how is this possible?

```cpp
1   void UTrace::DrawDebug()
2   {
3       for (TPair<Vector2DTuple, int> edge : EdgesMap)
4       {
5           Vector2DTuple vertices = edge.Key;
6           FVector source = FVector(*vertices.Key, 0.f);
7           FVector target = FVector(*vertices.Value, 0.f);     
8
9           DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), source, target, FColor::Black, false, -1.f, -1, 3.f);
10          UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f %f %f"), source.X, source.Y, source.Z);
11          UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f %f %f"), target.X, target.Y, target.Z);
12          UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("-------"));
13      }
14  }
```

I have a breakpoint on line 9 and 11. In the game mode runtime, after the EdgesMap is filled with some element, the breakpoint on line 9 is hit.
In this moment the variables seem uninitialized.

[image: local variables on breakpoint is hit for the first time]

Then I press F5 to continue the program and the breakpoint is hit again on line 9 (not line 11 as I would assume). And one of the variables in initialized and the other one is not.

[image: local variables on breakpoint is hit for the second time]

Then continue the program and the breakpoint is hit again on line 9 and no UE_LOG was executed so far.

[image: local variables on breakpoint is hit for the third time]

After that, I continue the program and finally the breakpoint on line 11 is hit and there is **one** log in the console with correctly initialized variables (x=150, y=650).

Questions:

- Is it some sort of weird Visual Studio behavior or is it some bug in my code?
- How can I tell if the line is really executed?
- Is it somehow linked to the initialization of a local variable?

Observations:

- This weird breakpoint occurs only on the line with the first Draw Debug method. If I put a different call few lines above, than this happens on the prior call.
- The collection EdgesMap has only one element (so the loop has only one iteration for one DrawDebug call)
- The DrawDebug method is only called from a onTick method (it is not called from some constructor)

Comment: This is possible if you debugging a release build code

Comment: You'll want to use a debug configuration, if you've built the engine yourself then you could use DebugGameEditor. Which means all game modules are compiled with no optimisations. I think the configuration for a pre built version is just called Debug.

Comment: Thanks, It really was due to the wrong configuration!
That opens a different question. Is there a reason in using debugger in Develop configuration? Can I rely on some parts or is the behavior completely undefined?